# mschart: Different background colors for different y-value ranges?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

Is there any way I can create a line chart using mschart where the chart area's background color changes for different ranges of y values?

For instance, a line chart would have a green background for y values 0 - 10, a yellow background for y values 10 - 20 and a red background for y values 20 - 30.

A gradient will not work, the colors must be solid.

I might have to use a background image, but I think there might be a better way.  Unfortunately, web searches haven't turned anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided the only way to do this is to use a background image.  Where needed I can use GDI+ to create the image at runtime with the proper height and width.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use custom labels feature of MSchart.

```
int element = Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(0, 10,"Low");
element = Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(10, 20, "Medium");
element = Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(20,30,"High");
```